# How to use 'if Token is'

Tags: tokens

I would like to use an if statement depending on my token something like

```
<?php if ([simplenews-category:name] == 'fishing'): ?>
 Go fishing   <?php else: ?>
 Go sailing    <?php endif ?>
```

Above code doesn't work, can somebody please give me advice?

I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the token first with it's actual value.  You can do this with [token_replace](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7)();

I haven't used simplenews yet, but you will need to do something along the lines of:

```
<?php if (token_replace('[simplenews-category:name]', array('node' => $node)) == 'fishing'): ?>
 Go fishing   <?php else: ?>
 Go sailing    <?php endif ?>
```

Once `[simplenews-category:name]` has been converted, string comparisons should work as intended.

As a note, you will likely need something other than `array('node' => $node)` to get this to function.